# How to pass an argument to a member function wrapped in std::function<void()>?

Tags: c++, std-function

At first it seemed clear that I shouldn't be able to do this, but then I discovered that it can be done with free functions.

Here is an example where I pass void() functions from Child to Parent. The parent calls the function when their Frame comes up.

I have figured out the syntax to pass free functions with arguments, but I can't figure out how to pass a member function of Child with an argument.

Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

void f_Free1()      { std::cout << "Hi there hello. I'm a free function without arguments."; }
void f_Free2(int i) { std::cout << "Hi there hello. I'm a free function with an argument. It's " << i; }

class Parent
{
    std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> Tasks;

protected:

    void addTask(unsigned int frame, std::function<void()> task) { Tasks[frame].push_back(task); }

public:

    virtual ~Parent() {}
    unsigned int Frame = 0;

    void tick()
    {
        if (Tasks.count(Frame))
        {
            for (auto task : Tasks[Frame]) 
            { 
                task(); 
            }
        }

        Frame++;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    void f_Child1()      { std::cout << "This is a private Child function without arguments. "; }
    void f_Child2(int i) { std::cout << "This is a private Child function with an argument. It's " << i; }

public:

    Child() 
    {
        addTask(3, f_Free1);
        addTask(5, [a = int(4)] () { f_Free2(a); } ); // THIS WORKS!!!

        addTask(7, std::function<void()> { std::bind(&Child::f_Child1, this) });
        addTask(9, std::function<void()> { std::bind([a = int(4)]() { &Child::f_Child2(a), this) } }); // CAN'T MAKE THIS WORK
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child child;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << child.Frame << "]";
        child.tick(); // runs tasks whose frames are up
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the `bind`.

Use `[this]() { f_Child1(); }` and `[this]() { f_Child(4); }`.

Also, the free version can be just `[]() { f_Free2(4); }`.

Comment: Maybe he can't use C++11 :)

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev The current working code does, so that is very unlikely.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev in OP code braces are used to initialize, so he uses at least C++11. `std::function` and `std::bind` was available in `C++03 tr1` in MSVC without `std::tr1` namespace (other compilers required this namespace) so I understand your doubts.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)'s syntax would be:

- `std::bind(&f_Free1)`
- `std::bind(&f_Free2, 4)`
- `std::bind(&Child::f_Child1, this)`
- `std::bind(&Child::f_Child2, this, 4)`

But [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is simpler for most people:

- `&f_Free1` is fine, else `[](){ return f_Free1(); }`
- `[](){ return f_Free2(4); }`
- `[this]() { return this->f_Child1(); )`
- `[this]() { return this->f_Child2(4); )`

`return` can be omitted here as functions return `void`.
`this->` can be omitted in lambda.
you might capture more or differently for arguments.